# parent parameter in wc_get_orders arguments WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

In WooCommerce `wc_get_orders()` [documentation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#general) there is an argument called `parent` which as following description:
Accepts an integer: post ID of the order parent.

What is the order parent and what is the use case of this argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent` argument is the same as other post types. for example, we generally see in the page hierarchy.

I might be wrong at some point but, with orders, it's used with `shop_order_refund` post type, whenever you have a partial refund a new post will generate with post type `shop_order_refund`, and the post parent id will be assigned on this post data.